# Search in a .csv file in C

Tags: c, csv

I'm doing a project in C, in which I need to search in a .csv file. However, there are some mistakes in the program, and I can't find them. Independently of the city I enter (existing in the file), the only thing that appears is "ERROR".
Can someone help me, please? Thanks!
(Sorry for my English, it isn't my first language...)

```
int search_date(){
char tem_max[10];
char tem_min[10];
char humidity[10];
char pressure[10];
char town[100];
char city[100];
int i=0;

printf("Enter the name of the town: ");    
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", town);

FILE *stream = fopen("cities2.csv", "r");

char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
    {
        char *tmp = strdup(line);
        if (i > 0) {
            strcpy(city, strtok(tmp, ",\n"));  
            strcpy(tem_max, strtok(NULL, ","));  
            strcpy(tem_min, strtok(NULL, ","));
            strcpy(humidity, strtok(NULL, ","));
            strcpy(pressure, strtok(NULL, ","));

            if (strcmp(city, town) == 0)
            {
                printf("Town - Maximum temperature - Minimum temperature - Humidity - Pressure\n");
                printf("%s - %s - %s - %s - %s\n",city, tem_max, tem_min, humidity, pressure);
            }
        i++;      
        free(tmp);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ERROR");
        }
    fclose(stream);
}
```

}

Comment: please provide an example of the file data and post a [mcve]

Comment: It appears quite impossible for `i` to ever be anything other than zero in this code, since it is initialized to zero and only gets incremented if it is already greater than zero.

Comment: I hope this is only an example you're posting and not production code, because the `strcpy` lines are horrible. One little mistake in the input stream, one column larger than you expect, and the whole thing blows up. Please check the return value of `strtok` and use `strncpy`, because the length of the destination is unknown.

Comment: Isn't this a similar assignment as this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755133/search-and-print-a-specific-line-from-a-csv-file-in-c

Comment: Given that the only purpose of the `i>0` check is to skip the first line of the file, you should just call `fgets` once before entering the `while` loop. Then you can get rid of `i` altogether.

Comment: @Pablo: there are quite a lot of similarities, but also key differences.

Comment: Robust CSV parsing is hard — for that, you need a library.  For crude CSV parsing, you can make your code work, more or less, but remember that `strtok()` treats adjacent delimiters as one, so you can't have empty fields if you parse with `strtok()`.  You should also check for errors — null pointers returned by `strtok()`.  It is not clear why the first `strtok()` has both newline and comma while none of the others do; the last, in particular, probably needs the newline more than any of them (unless there are unparsed fields after the pressure).

Comment: @Pablo: In fact, the code has similarities, because I know the author of that question in person and she's doing almost the same project as me, but we can't help each other because she decided to start a new project. And thanks for the tips, despite they're not working. I had to change the code I posted anyway, because it didn't completely correspond with what I really needed.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `i` to `0`, then check if it is greater than `0` before you ever increment it.  Looking at your code, I really have no idea what the purpose of `i` is.  Even if the first test passes, all you do is increment `i` and keep reading.  Maybe you are trying to skip reading the first line of the file?

```
int search_date(){
char tem_max[10];
char tem_min[10];
char humidity[10];
char pressure[10];
char town[100];
char city[100];
int i=0;                                             // <--- i is 0

printf("Enter the name of the town: ");    
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", town);

FILE *stream = fopen("cities2.csv", "r");

char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
    {
        char *tmp = strdup(line);
        if (i > 0) {                                // <--- i is still 0
            strcpy(city, strtok(tmp, ",\n"));  
            strcpy(tem_max, strtok(NULL, ","));  
            strcpy(tem_min, strtok(NULL, ","));
            strcpy(humidity, strtok(NULL, ","));
            strcpy(pressure, strtok(NULL, ","));

            if (strcmp(city, town) == 0)
            {
                printf("Town - Maximum temperature - Minimum temperature - Humidity - Pressure\n");
                printf("%s - %s - %s - %s - %s\n",city, tem_max, tem_min, humidity, pressure);
            }
        i++;                                      // <--- now you do i++
        free(tmp);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ERROR");
        }
    fclose(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Stephen Docy is right. Already he pointed out your mistake. I have just modified your code so that it should work for you.

```
int search_date(){
   char tem_max[10];
   char tem_min[10];
   char humidity[10];
   char pressure[10];
   char town[100];
   char city[100];
   int i=1;                                             // <--- now i is 1

   printf("Enter the name of the town: ");    
   scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", town);

   FILE *stream = fopen("cities2.csv", "r");

   char line[1024];
   while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
   {
       char *tmp = strdup(line);
       if (i > 0) {                                // <--- i is now > 0
        strcpy(city, strtok(tmp, ",\n"));  
        strcpy(tem_max, strtok(NULL, ","));  
        strcpy(tem_min, strtok(NULL, ","));
        strcpy(humidity, strtok(NULL, ","));
        strcpy(pressure, strtok(NULL, ","));

        if (strcmp(city, town) == 0)
        {
            printf("Town - Maximum temperature - Minimum temperature - Humidity - Pressure\n");
            printf("%s - %s - %s - %s - %s\n",city, tem_max, tem_min, humidity, pressure);
        }
      i++;                                      // <--- now you do i++
      free(tmp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR");
    }
  fclose(stream);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the fix.  I held off doing so until the poster explained what he was trying to use `i` for, since removing `i` and using `if (1)` would have the same effect.

Comment: true he don't even need that `if` condition as he is not using `i` anywhere in his code.