# How to edit .csv files in C

Tags: c, csv

I'm new at programming, and I need help in my C project. I have to search for a city, confirm it exists in the first file (city.csv), and take its id from there. Then I have to match that id with the corresponding one in the second file (meteo.csv), and then edit its weather information, that is in that second file. However, I don't know how I can take the city id from the first file, and then how to edit the second file after obtaining all the new weather informations. Here is the code:

```
void addInfo() {
FILE * fp;
char id_city[100];    
char city[100];    
char humidity[100];    
char temp_max[100];    
char temp_min[100];
char pressure[100];
char date[100];   

printf("Name of the city: ");
scanf("%s", city);


// I think it's here that I have to write the code for take the city's id from the first file

if (id_city != NULL) {
    printf("Maximun temperature: ");
    scanf("%s", temp_max);
    printf("Minimun temperature: ");
    scanf("%s", temp_min);
    printf("Humidity: ");
    scanf("%s", humidity);
    printf("Pressure: ");
    scanf("%s", pressure);
    printf("Date, in the format YYYY-MM-DD: ");
    scanf("%s", date);

    fp = fopen ("meteo.csv", "a");
    fprintf(fp, "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s \n", temp_max, temp_min, humidity, pressure, date); //I think there's something wrong here too...

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Information edited successfully");

}
```

The file city.csv has 152 lines and 4 columns:

```
(id_city,city,county,district)
```

such as

```
(56,Lisbon,Lisbon,Lisbon)
```

The file meteo.csv has 152 lines and 7 columns:

```
(id_meteo_city,id_city,temp_max,temp_min,humidity,pressure,date)
```

such as

```
(56,56,14,5,62,1025,2018-02-12)
```

Comment: The task is pretty clear. Where exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755923/search-in-a-csv-file-in-c

Comment: The line `if (id_city != NULL)` cannot be `NULL` because you have defined `char id_city[100] = "11";` (irrespective of the actual data). At what level are you stuck?

Comment: @Dagan: That question was mine, in fact... But I found that I can't do it that way... Maybe I'll just delete that question...

Comment: @Pablo: I never worked with files before, to tell you the truth. I'm in college and teachers didn't talk about files at all. I have a code that can search in the city.csv file, that is similar to the first question I asked here, and it works as I expected. I don't know how can I take the id_city from there, to use in this code, and if I can use the code I have for searching in this case. Furthermore, I'm not sure if the last code lines are correct to append the information in the meteo.csv file... Sorry if I was a little confuse...

Comment: @WeatherVane: I deleted the "11", now that I think about it, it doesn't make sense... I explained above what my problem was to Pablo. And again, sorry if I was a little confuse...

Comment: To *"edit"* a file in C, you can do one of two things. 1) Read the whole file into memory, modify the file, write the file back to disk. 2) Create a temporary file. Copy the original file to the temporary file while making any changes needed. Delete the original file and rename the temporary file.

Comment: @user3386109: So the way I appended in the end of my code is wrong? How can I do that? (Sorry, as I said somewhere, I never worked with files before, and as much as I searched on the Internet, is very difficult find something useful about how to work in .csv using C...)

Comment: The problem with appending is that you didn't delete the previous weather data for the city. Which is to say that you didn't *"edit"* the city's weather data, you added a duplicate entry for the city. I would read the whole file into memory using `fgets` to read lines. Parse each line with `sscanf`, storing the information in an array of structures. Then modify the weather for the chosen city, and write the new data back to the file. That's the best I can do for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is encapsulate the data in a `struct`, that makes it
easier to map a line of a CSV file into an object representing a line.

If both files `city.csv` and `meteo.csv` have different columns, I'd create a
different `struct` for each file. If both files have the same columns, you could
use the `struct`. I assume that both files are different and that `city` has the
format `meteo_id,city_id,name`.

```
typedef struct city_t {
    int meteo_id;
    int city_id;
    char name[100];  // no city should have
                     // longer than 100 chars
} city_t;

typedef struct meteo_t {
    int meteo_id;
    int city_id;
    int tempt_max;
    int tempt_mix;
    double humidity;
    double preassure;
    char date[11];
} meteo_t;
```

Let's assume that both files are well formatted, otherwise you would have to
write code that checks for errors and handles them, that would be the next step
in the exercise, so I'm going to write only the basic version with basic error
recognition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

// takes 2 params, the filename and a pointer
// to size_t where the number of cities is stored
city_t *read_cities(const char *filename, size_t *len)
{
    if(filename == NULL || len == NULL)
        return NULL;

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }

    city_t *arr = NULL, *tmp;
    *len = 0;

    // assuming that no line will be longer than 1023 chars long
    char line[1024];

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
    {
        tmp = realloc(arr, (*len + 1) * sizeof *arr);
        if(tmp == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "could not parse the whole file %s\n", filename);
            // returning all parsed cities so far

            if(*len == 0)
            {
                free(arr);
                arr = NULL;
            }

            return arr;
        }

        arr = tmp;

        // %99[^\n] is to read up to 99 characters until the end of the line
        if(sscanf(line, "%d,%d,%99[^\n]", &(arr[*len].meteo_id),
                    &(arr[*len].city_id), arr[*len].name) != 3)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid line format (skipping line):\n%s\n", line);
            // skip this line, and decrement *len
            (*len)--;
            continue;
        }

        // incrementing only when parsing of line was OK
        (*len)++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    // file is empty or
    // all lines have wrong format
    if(*len == 0)
    {
        free(arr);
        arr = NULL;
    }


    return arr;
}

void print_cities(city_t *cities, size_t len, FILE *fp)
{
    if(cities == NULL || fp == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        fprintf(fp, "%d,%d,%s\n", cities[i].meteo_id, cities[i].citiy_id,
                cities[i].name);
}
```

Now I've written the read and write functions for the file `citiy.csv` assuming the
format `meteo_id;city_id;name`. The `print_cities` allows you to print the CSV
content on the screen (passing `stdout` as the last argument) or to a file
(passing a `FILE` object as the last argument).

You can use these functions as templates for reading and writing `meteo.csv`, the
idea is the same.

You can use these function as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
    size_t cities_len;
    city_t *cities = read_cities("city.csv", &cities_len);

    // error
    if(cities == NULL)
        return 1;

    do_something_with_cities(cities, cities_len);

    // update csv
    FILE *fp = fopen("city.csv", "w");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open city.csv for reading: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));

        free(cities);
        return 1;
    }

    print_cities(cities, cities_len, fp);

    fclose(fp);
    free(cities);
    return 0;
}
```

Now for your exercise: write a similar function that parses `meteo.csv` (using
my function as a template shouldn't be that difficult) and parse both files. Now
that you've got them in memory, it's easy to manipulate the data (insert,
update, delete). Then write the files like I did in the example and that's it.

One last hint: how to search for a city:

```
// returns the index in the array or -1 on error or when not found
int search_for_city_by_name(city_t *cities, size_t len, const char *name)
{
    if(cities == NULL || name == NULL)
        return -1;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        if(strcmp(name, cities[i].name) == 0)
            return i;

    // not found
    return -1;
}
```

Now I have given you almost all parts of the assignment, all you have to do is
stick them together and write the same functions for the `meteo.csv` file.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just didn't understand, in the 3rd code, what do you mean with the function "do_something_with_cities"? And sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: `do_something_with_cities` is just a place holder for your work with the cities array. You can do the work directly in `main` or in other function.

Answer (score 0):

To edit one field:

```
void _ERR(char a) {
if (a == "f") printf("\n\tError File !!\n\n");
if (a == "m") printf("\n\tError Memory !!\n\n");
exit(1); }

char* stmm(const char* src) {
char* dst = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);
if (dst == NULL) return NULL;  
strcpy(dst, src);
return dst; }

const char* getfield(char* line, int num) {
const char* tok;
for (tok = strtok(line, ",");
    tok && *tok;
    tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
{
    if (!--num)
        return tok;
}
return NULL; }

void edit_file(char* FName, char* NewValue, int row, int col) {
int i, r = 0, c;
char line[1024];
FILE* fr, * fw;
fr = fopen(FName, "r");
fw = fopen(FName, "r+");
if (fr == NULL|| fw == NULL) _ERR("f");
while (fgets(line, 1024, fr))
{
    char* tmp = stmm(line);
    if (tmp == NULL) _ERR("m");
    for (i = 0, c = 1; i < strlen(tmp); i++) {
        if (tmp[i] == 44) c++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if (r == row && i+1 == col) {
            fprintf(fw,"%s", NewValue);
        } else {
            free(tmp);
            tmp = stmm(line);
            if (tmp == NULL) _ERR("m");
            fprintf(fw,"%s", getfield(tmp, i + 1));
        }
        (i < c - 1) ? fprintf(fw,",") : fprintf(fw,"\n");
    }
    free(tmp);
    r++;
}
fclose(fr);
fclose(fw); }
```

edit_file(".\FileName.csv","NewValue",Row,Column);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).